# Are administrator layout overrides lost in system's templates on Joomla's update?

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override, isis-template

Let's say I need an alternative layout of an administrator module. So I copy the file of the module from the `administrator/modules/my_module/tmpl/default.php` and put it inside `administrator/templates/isis/html/my_module/default.php`.

And here is my question: Am I going to loose this created folder/file on Joomla's update since `isis` is default Joomla's administrator template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be safe. The "Isis" administrator template layouts do not get updated when the core of Joomla! is updated. Technically, the template is not part of the core code.

To verify the update date of a template, you would typically look at the details of the template in *Extensions > Templates > Templates*. For Administrator templates, you would select "Administrator" as the type. You will see the "Version" is "1.0" and the "Date" is "3/30/2012" for Isis. However, for this template, the date and version are inaccurate as the Joomla! team has not accurately documented their updates.

*Important:* With all customizations that you make, always keep a backup locally in case something happens (of course, you should be keeping a backup of the entire site, anyway).

Comment: Yes, it's safe to do so because layouts in the template don't get overridden, however updates **are** actually made to the Isis template pretty much every Joomla release. It's just the version and date that don't get updated.

Comment: @Lodder, thanks for your input. Sounds like the Joomla! team is failing at proper coding documentation. Just another reason why Joomla! can't keep up with WordPress... :/

Comment: We do our best to add features to the CMS to make the lives for users such as yourself easier. Yes, the documentation needs updating, just like many other things in Joomla. The documentation is open to the public so feel free to make changes. Anyone can moan about X, Y and Z when they don't contribute to the core. As for Wordpress, well yeah, I suppose you gotta love a insecure and crap code base CMS

Comment: @Lodder, sorry to strike a nerve with you. I do use both CMSs equally. But, I was only stating the obvious. Hopefully, the Joomla! team isn't covering their eyes to that.

Comment: I added "layouts" to the answer to make it more accurate.